# Dictionary from List in Python based on length of list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, string-length

I have the following list in python

```
 days = ['Saturday', 'Monday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Tuesday', 'Sunday', 
        'Wednesday']
```

I want to create the following dictionary

```
dayweek = {'Saturday': 1, 'Monday': 2, 'Thursday': 3, 'Friday': 4, 'Tuesday': 
5, 'Sunday': 6, 'Wednesday': 7}
```

I have tried the following code

```
     dayweek=dict(enumerate(days))
```

This yields the following result

```
  {0: 'Saturday', 1: 'Monday', 2: 'Thursday', 3: 'Friday', 4: 'Tuesday', 5: 
  'Sunday', 6: 'Wednesday'}
```

How do i accomplish the same

I request someone to help me

Comment: Check the question linked by @Aran-Fey and use `enumerate(days, 1)` to handle your offset.

Comment: Thank you. It ha solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out:

```
dict([(j, i) for i, j in enumerate(days, 1)])
```

Comment: You create an intermediate list before building a dict out of it, this is inefficient and much slower than using a dict comprehension, see my answer. Some timing: on my machine, the dict comprehension takes 1.66µs, your solution takes 3.08µs

Comment: makes sense. I typically do not dig into the details for 7 items but of cause Thierry is right.

Answer (score 3):

You can give a starting value of 1 to `enumerate` and use a dictionary comprehension:

```
days = ['Saturday', 'Monday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Tuesday', 'Sunday', 
        'Wednesday']

dayweek = { day:index for index, day in enumerate(days, 1)}
print(dayweek)

# {'Saturday': 1, 'Monday': 2, 'Thursday': 3, 'Friday': 4, 'Tuesday': 5, 'Sunday': 6, 'Wednesday': 7}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> m={d:i+1 for i,d in enumerate(days)}
>>> m
{'Saturday': 1, 'Monday': 2, 'Thursday': 3, 'Friday': 4, 'Tuesday': 5, 'Sunday': 6, 'Wednesday': 7}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
dict(zip(days, range(1, len(days)+1)))
```

Output :

```
{'Monday': 2, 'Tuesday': 5, 'Friday': 4, 'Wednesday': 7, 'Thursday': 3, 'Sunday': 6, 'Saturday': 1}
```